# Get current font

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

How could I get the current font, notably when it is set with `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`? I tried `\l_fontspec_font`, `\f@family` and `\l_fontspec_family_tl` but none of them contains exactly the name of the font, so that:

```
\setmainfont{\f@family}
```

is a no-op. (notably, it removes the space in the name of the font, which seems to be fine for lualatex but not for xelatex).

Any idea how to get the current font, and ideally save its name to reset it later?

MWE:

```
% compile with xelatex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\makeatletter
\show\f@family
% this works with lualatex but not with xelatex:
\setmainfont{\f@family}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hey
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

It might be simpler to explain why I want to recover the `Times New Roman` name: in short, I want to get the font in file A and reuse it in file B. More precisely, for now people of my robust-externalize library need to manually load the font in the cached file, with something like:

```
\robExtConfigure{
    add to preset={latex}{
        add to preamble={\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}},
    },
}
```

This is fine if the font does not change, but if it changes often in the document, it can be quite a mess to get it right as the user needs to update the font manually. For now, I recommend to [xelatex users](https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/issues/13) to create a new `\mysetmainfont` like:

```
% Create a new command \mysetmainfont which forwards the font to the picture.
\NewDocumentCommand{\mysetmainfont}{m}{%
  \def\myCurrentFont{#1}% Stores the name of the current font in \myCurrentFont
  \setmainfont{#1}%
}

% Use mysetmainfont from now to change font:
\mysetmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\robExtConfigure{
  add to preset={latex}{
    use xelatex,
    set placeholder eval={__MY_FONT__}{\myCurrentFont},
    add to preamble={
      \usepackage{fontspec}
      \setmainfont{__MY_FONT__}
    },
  },
}
```

but I feel there must be a better solution to get the name of the font in file A and reuse it in file B. Any better solution?

Comment: This looks like it might be an XY-problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: by "name" here you seem to mean "an argument valid for `\setmainfont` which isn't really a name at all. the `(0)` you show for example indicates that is one of the fonts loaded by that command with a particular set of font deatures.

Comment: @Skillmon cf my edit

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, as I explained in my edit, I want basically to copy the font setting from file A to file B, so ideally using a valid argument to `\setmainfont`, or any other robust enough solution.

Comment: your question is still completely unclear what is the input to the question. If you have the whole first document just redefine `\setmainfont` to save its argument to another file for you to use. If you are looking at one point in the first document at the current font, you can of course ony make a rough guess whether `\setmainfont` is used at all or what its argument was. `\setmainfont` doesn't just specify one font it specifies a whole range including bold and italic at all sizes you can only guess what is used for italic and bold..

Comment: Just saving the font name isn't enough. What you actually want is to save the whole `\setmainfont` declaration, including options.

Comment: to put it another way `\def\myCurrentFont{#1}% Stores the name of the current font in \myCurrentFont`  that is what you should do (also save the options), but the comment is very misleading, #1 does not refer to a "current font" but a  default font family. If the point that you externalise the current font is times Italic bold, you still want (I assume) to construct `\setmainfont(Times New Roman}`  (or do you want to preserve italic/bold, in which case why use `\setmainfont` ???

Comment: As you can see in the log \setmainfont setups 8 different font shapes (it could be more if you use options). Without making use of fontspec internals or redefining fontspec commands it would be very difficult to reverse engineer that. Define some command \robExtfontsetup which can both stores and execute its argument and so can transport the commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok thanks. I was hoping that it would be easy to know the name/size/bold of the font used at current point, and to restore it in one command in another file… but seems like (latex) life is never easy ^^

Comment: it is easy to find out *one* font. But this is not what you want. You want to find out and copy the overall font *setup* which contains lots of fonts with various options.

Comment: @tobiasBora it is easy to record the font at one point and restore it but that is not what you want. You want to restore an entire font setup from just that one piece of information which is impossible whether or not you use latex. It is like saying from the current `\hsize` it is easy to save and restore that one length but you can not infer an entire page layout geometry just given that information.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell you are looking for a name to use in the latex font selection not the opentype font name. `fontspec` will assign a font family but if you are going to be using it it's easier to assign a memorable one so something like

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[NFSSFamily=tmsnr]{Times New Roman}
\makeatletter
\show\f@family
% this does nothing here as the family is already selected, but may be used in other contexts,
\fontfamily{tmsnr}\selectfont
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hey
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the `NFSSFamily`, its interesting. But it might not be as resiliant as I want for my application, as I'd like the name to be "absolute", so that I do not need to write it in the second file as well (cf my edit).

Comment: your question is still very hard to understand, why do you have `\setmainfont{TimesNewRoman(0)}` if that works anywhere it only works by accident` the syntax should be `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` if using the internalfont name, or use the filename with its extension.

Comment: I guess my question is unclear because I am not aware of how exactly font works in LaTeX and fontspec. (and `\setmainfont{TimesNewRoman(0)}` was supposed to be `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`, but for some reasons lualatex seems to accept this other version which is the one contained in `\f@family` by default) At a high level, I just want to know the font at point A, and generate a code that I’ll write into another file to reuse the font at point A, ideally without assuming anything on the font at point A.

Comment: What you propose seems to work (if we don't care about size and bold…), but assumes that I manually copied `\setmainfont[NFSSFamily=tmsnr]{Times New Roman}` in the second file, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @tobiasBora yes the question has been edited since I posted this. But I don't think the new version is really answerable, I think you need some package-specific way of capturing the whole preamble of the first document, trying to reconstruct a `\setmainfont` that may never have been there seems doomed to failure.

Comment: @tobiasBora "but for some reasons lualatex seems to accept this other version" luatex ignores white space and upper/lower case by design. The `(0)` is an internal identifier to allow the same underlying font to be loaded with different font features, if it works in `\fontspec` that is just by accident and can not be relied on.

Comment: @tobiasBora have you tried adding parameters like `BoldFont`, `ItalicFont`, `BoldItalicFont`? This is in response to "What you propose seems to work (if we don't care about size and bold…)"